# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-10

Before installing windows 10 new update and jdk updates if I wanted to type (') with Robot class I just had to use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
}
```

And this had been working for me.
But now after installing windows 10 new update and jdk updates if I use it, I face with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key 
code
at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)
at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

All other keys are working except (VK_QUOTE);
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Other questions in SO on the same subject sugest this functionality is related to the keyboard layout. Is your keyboard configured in the same way as before the updates?

Comment: problem solved. thank you Juan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard input method(*Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Language options*) was on 'United States-International Touch keyboard layout'.
and I changed it to 'US' now it works properly.